# Div 100% width cross browser firefox issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

If you look at http://www2.currensee.com in safari the page width is fine, but in firefox (3.6 at least) there is a horizontal scroll. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I don't see the problem in FF6. I don't have FF3.6 on this machine. However, you are using the XHTML doctype which is for XML applications only. You should change it to XHTML v.1.0 instead.

Comment: If you're not happy with a horizontal scroll bar in FF, don't load that page in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine in FF6. You could try the CSS3 style `html { overflow-x:hidden; }` but I'm not sure if it was implemented in FF3.6.

Comment: I have overflow:hidden in general being used, so that should be occurring anyway

Answer (score 0):

if width is 100% and margin is > 0 you will get a scroll bar because the margin is extending outside the visible area.

Comment: I think you're referring to padding. Margin shouldn't affect the size of the element, but padding definitely will.

Answer (score 0):

A box shadow was causing the error.